# Передача свойства с метод с модификатором ref и out

Tags: c#, .net

Можно ли как-нибудь обойти запрет на передачу свойства в метод с модификаторами?

Например, у меня есть поле, на этом поле висит свойство, которое контролирует корректную модификацию данного поля.

Из-за того, что я не могу передать свойство в метод у меня не получается цетролизованно сделать проверку перед присвоением.

Или мой подход некорректен и есть какой-то другой выход?

Comment: Ну а чем временная переменная не угодила? Передавайте в out/ref ее, а потом присваивайте ее значение свойству

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1402803/2881286

Comment: хочешь использовать свойства с `ref`/`out` [переходи на VB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/564813/2881286)

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял вашу проблему (да, кусок кода не помешал бы), то вам надо вынести логику проверки в отдельный метод и вызывать его внутри свойства и внутри вашего метода с ref/out. Тем самым вы не продублируете код проверки, но сможете вызывать его из двух разных мест.

Answer (score 2):

Одна из причин по которой нельзя передавать свойство с метод с ref/out параметрами - это модификаторы доступа свойств:

Представьте что свойство доступно только для чтения? Разумеется присвоить в методе значение уже будет нельзя.

```
private int _prop;
public int Prop
{
    get { return _prop; }
    private set { _prop = value; }
}
```

Мое предложение - это обернуть ваше свойство в класс и передавать уже объект в метод.

Answer (score 0):

Одна из причин указана выше. А вот одно из решений не нарушающих ООП:

```
public class Product
{
    public string Barcode { get; private set; }

    public bool SetBarcode(string barcode)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(barcode))
        {
            Barcode = barcode;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Класс обработчика

```
public class Issuer
{
    public bool IssueBarcode(string barcode, Func<string, bool> setter)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(barcode))
        {
            return setter(DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Использование

```
 var product = new Product();
 var issuer = new Issuer();

 issuer.IssueBarcode(product.Barcode, product.SetBarcode);
```

Как говорится, и волки сыты и овцы целы.

Comment: Ну а если нарушая - через рефлексию вы доберетесь до сеттера оригинального.